# If $AA^T$ is the zero matrix, then $A$ is the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. Show that if $A^TA$ or $AA^T$ is the zero matrix, then $A$ is the zero matrix.

I feel very close to solving the problem so far. I have said that

$$[0]_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^4 [A]_{ik}[A^T]_{kj} =\sum_{k=1}^4 [A]_{ik}[A]_{jk} \qquad \text{for all }i,j \in \{1,2,3,4\} $$

and proven for the case if $i=j$. However, I cannot seem to find a good way to prove it to be true if $i\neq j$.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "if $i\neq j$". You use $i=j$ to show that the $i$th row (or column) must be all 0. Hence you're done.

Comment: When you say "if $i = j$" or "if $i \neq j$", it's almost as if you think that $i$ and $j$ are fixed and given. They are not, the equality you've written holds for *all* possible pairs $(i, j)$. That is, you have established $4 \times 4 = 16$ equalities. You are free to use any of them. You can use some of these equalities and ignore the others if you like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An idea: if we put $\;A=(a_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}\;$ , then $\,A^t=(b_{ij})\;$ , with $\,b_{ij}=a_{ji}\,$ , so by definition:

$$AA^t=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}\right)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{jk}\right)$$

If you now look at the main diagonal's general entry of the above, you get

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}a_{ik}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}^2$$

So if $\,AA^t=0\;$ then the above diagonal's entries are zero, but a sum of squared *real* numbers is zero iff each number is zero, so...

The same result is true with complex matrices if instead we require $\,AA^*=0\;,\;\;A^*:=\overline{A^t}\;$

Answer (score 8):

Here's a more matrix algebraic, less coordinate dependent way to do it:  for any matrix $M$, we have $\langle M^Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, My \rangle$ for the standard inner product.  Then if $A^TA = 0$, $\langle x, A^TAx \rangle =0$, so $\langle Ax, Ax\rangle =0$, whence $Ax = 0$ for all $x$, whence $A = 0$.  Same idea works if $AA^T = 0$.  Cheers.

Comment: Above answer is for real matrices, of course!

Comment: +1 Nice answer, though I'm not sure whether the OP, asking such a basic question, has already covered inner product spaces, conjugate matrices and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Look at matrix $A$ as column vectors

$$A = [c_1, c_2, \cdots, c_n]$$

Then the $i$-th diagonal element of $A^T A$ is $c_i^T c_i = 0$, this indicates $c_i = 0, i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$. Thus $A = 0$.

Comment: Basically the same answer as DonAntonio 9 years ago. Try something new: the trace of $AA^T$ is $||A||_F^2$.