# Matrices: proving that $AA^t=0$ implies $A=0$

Tags: matrices

I know that applying trace of $AA^t$ gives $A=0$, but I was trying to formalise the proof I thought:

Suposse $A≠0$. Then for every $X$, $A+X≠X$.
So $(A+X)A^t≠XA^t$ for every $X$, arriving in $XA^t≠XA^t$, a contradiction, therefore $A=0$.

But I realise it may not be always true that $A+X≠X$ implies $(A+X)A^t≠XA^t$. But as we can pick any $X$, it seems that the proof is sufficient,  but not formal enough, so I am looking for an improvement in this demonstration

I now know that it is a good idea to look to $X^tAA^tX=0$ for any $X$, wich implies $A^tX=0$, concluding the proof, but why is this implication true?

Comment: That question was already asked before. You can take a look at the answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435880/if-aat-is-the-zero-matrix-then-a-is-the-zero-matrix

Comment: This is true for real matrices, but not true for complex matrices.

Comment: Let $X$ be any column vector, then $X^tAA^tX=0$ is equivalent to $A^tX=0$ . This implies your result!

Comment: Why is $X^tAA^tX=0$ equivalent to $A^tX=0$?

Comment: $A^tX$ is a column vector,   $X^tA$ is a  row vector and $(X^tA)^=A^tX.$

Comment: What I dont' follow is that I know $(X^tA)^t=A^tX$, but that only means that $X^tAA^tX=0$ is the same as $(X^tA)^t(X^tA)=0$, wich is the same as $BB^t=0$ and you are saying $B=0$, but that is what I want to prove

Answer (score 1):

You use that $A\neq B$ implies that $CA\neq CB$. However, this is not true in general (already for $C=0$ it is not true, but also for nonzero $C$). To say, "we can pick any $X$" is not a valid argument, I think.

Comment: I know but what I mean is that if we pick any $X$ that makes that inequality true, it ends the proof, but I don't know if that $X$ exists

Comment: So it is not a valid proof, right? Why not just take the [standard proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435880/if-aat-is-the-zero-matrix-then-a-is-the-zero-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1)...

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of your first (or last) remark: Since $\langle A^t Ax, x\rangle = \langle Ax, Ax\rangle$ vanishes for any $x$, the matrix $A = 0$.